# Pandas dataframe splitting without sorting or iterating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a dataframe where it's important to keep the order. I would like to split it into chunks that I process afterwards.

The splitting is done based on the 3rd column `type`, all contiguous records with the same value of columns type (or any given categorical column) should be in one chunk, and if possible i want to done it in a pythonic way.

but I can only think of solutions where I iterate through the df.  Consider that this will have to work on dataframes with tens of thousands of entries roughly, and I have no idea of the fastest strategy to do so. Here is a small example of what I have:

```
     value_1   value_2 type
0  -0.005842 -0.494596    a
1   0.697689  0.354717    a
2  -0.354206 -1.776550    a
3   2.154078  0.344629    a
4   1.072475  1.004945    a
5  -1.338075  0.175607    b
6  -1.913883 -0.123627    b
7  -0.021376 -0.170775    b
8  -0.274882 -0.043913    b
9   0.676371 -0.691243    b
10  0.440201 -0.577944    c
11 -0.689345 -0.445433    b
12  1.540386 -1.084499    c
13  0.236204 -0.072807    b
14 -0.257084  0.848501    c
15  0.681666 -0.265254    b
16 -1.168614 -0.359998    c
17  0.355938  1.529444    b
18  0.292976 -0.301847    c
19  0.670068  0.735191    b
20  0.551594 -0.074768    a
21 -1.251568 -0.022201    a
22  0.376663 -1.556191    a
23 -0.266714  0.860436    d
24 -0.871324  1.014529    d
25  1.504529 -0.657725    d
```

And here is how I would like to split it

```
    value_1   value_2 type
0  1.411723 -0.836490    a
1  0.482826  1.625925    a
2 -0.054475  2.046166    a
3  0.020816  0.155194    a
4  0.840539  0.287658    a
    value_1   value_2 type
5  0.257208 -2.311165    b
6 -1.545194 -0.193307    b
7  0.197849 -1.276644    b
8  0.074072 -0.172764    b
9 -2.562816  0.393645    b
     value_1   value_2 type
10  0.258265 -0.978293    c
     value_1  value_2 type
11 -0.804841 -0.78802    b
     value_1   value_2 type
12 -0.509034  1.116428    c
     value_1   value_2 type
13 -0.264252  1.025199    b
     value_1   value_2 type
14 -0.268105 -0.795613    c
     value_1   value_2 type
15  0.481051  0.184827    b
     value_1   value_2 type
16  1.242139  0.401806    c
     value_1   value_2 type
17  1.301684  0.281108    b
     value_1   value_2 type
18  0.189178  0.894425    c
     value_1   value_2 type
19 -0.093207  0.894564    b
     value_1   value_2 type
20 -2.231735  0.250696    a
21 -0.276050 -0.712792    a
22  0.298974 -0.529791    a
     value_1   value_2 type
23  0.115159  2.769695    d
24  0.636069 -1.066387    d
25  1.048230  1.500125    d
```

Something like a groupby that gives back just a list of slices according to the value of the chosen column would be perfect, I haven't found any existing function like that

Comment: what is your criteria to split the dataframe ?

Comment: Same value in "type" column, but without putting together all the rows that satisfy the condition. I need to keep the chunks in order to make it easier to process after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom group and `groupby` to split your data:

```
df.groupby(df['type'].ne(df['type'].shift()).cumsum())
```

Then you can iterate over it:

```
groups = df.groupby(df['type'].ne(df['type'].shift()).cumsum())

for group_id, group_df in groups:
    # do stuff
```